# How to query a maximum of a list?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a list (in this example: list of cars) in my stock. I want to query for the stock and find the highest price that is available within the cars list.

```
class Stock {
    List<Car> cars;
}

class Car {
    int price;
}
```

Tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.cars.price FROM Stock s;
```

But this always gives an "error in named query". What could be wrong, or how could this be done better?

Comment: Please add you Hibernate code.

Comment: Your query is not finding out maximum at any point? Is it exactly what you are using?

Comment: no it's not exactly what I'm using, but I tracked the expression down to the one above, and even this does not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
Object maxPrice = session.createQuery("select max(car.price) from Stock s join s.cars car").uniqueResult();
```